# Can You Do Data Binding With CSS?

Tags: html, css, data-binding

I want to pass urls from database into my CSS in order to show the correct image, can you do this?

For example, right now I have this in HTML:

```
<div class="img-bg bg-6 bg-grad-layer-6"></div>
```

and this bg-6 in CSS:

```
.bg-6{ background: url(../images/slider-6-450x600.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size: cover; }
```

I already have access to my database and I know how to get the url for the photos that are stored, is there anyway that I can pass the urls into bg-6 to be used in url(database url here) instead of that static file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set inline style.

An example from ejs.

```
<div class="img-bg bg-6 bg-grad-layer-6" style="background-image:url('<%= data %>');"></div>
```

This adaptable any other language.

Or can give to class.

```
<style>
.bg-6{ background: url('<%= data %>') no-repeat center; background-size: cover; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers cache css files. If you are changing your css file every time someone visits your site, they may not get the newest data every visit. You could set your server up to tell the browser not to cache the files, but then you are adding extra overhead and removing the real benefit of caching.

You should just use one good css file and then update the urls in your server language (something like PHP) or in JavaScript.

In JavaScript, you can use `element.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/slider-6-450x600.jpg')";` where `element` is a reference to the element you want to change.

In PHP you could just add inline style attributes like `<div style="background-image: url('../images/slider-6-450x600.jpg')"></div>`.

If you want to change the value for an entire class, you could use something like PHP to add a `<style>` tag at the top of your document with the custom values.